# SemanticImport::unexpinvaliderr error when using trial version

Tags: import, files-and-directories

I am trying to use [`SemanticImport`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SemanticImport.html) for a personal experiment.
I can correctly import a *tsv* file from a path, but if I change [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) to `SemanticImport`, I get the error

> *SemanticImport::unexpinvaliderr: Unexpected invalid input was detected.  Processing will not continue*

This leads to no explanation on the guide. I tried to run the usual example

```
SemanticImport["ExampleData/RetailSales.tsv"]
```

And I get the same error.

I am using a trial version of latest *Mathematica* 10.0.1.0, with no other packages installe (it's actually the out-of-the-box version).

Am I doing something wrong? Is there some limitation in the Trial version?

Comment: The trial version is probably to blame, yes. See the last answer in [this](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/290610) thread. The `Import` capabilities are limited.

Comment: Well, this is pretty lame, since I already knew old versions of Mathematica and I wanted to try the new semantic functionalities. Thank you for your answer!